Azure Web Service deploys with wrong version of Node
I'm trying to deploy a service using Node v18
Indeed, in settings < Configurations I have set it to node v18

The command
az webapp config show  --resource-group <RG-name> --name <ServiceName> --query linuxFxVersion
confirms the version to be v18: "NODE|18.20.1"
Even the actual docker container being used seems to correspond to v18:
                                V
2024-08-12T17:08:30.841Z INFO - 18-lts_20220228.1.tuxprod Pulling from appsvc/node
2024-08-12T17:08:30.852Z INFO - Digest: sha256:151be8808b6230b7f1d902cf9fb20cd796016a00bd9a32c45910d6a5fe6c473c
2024-08-12T17:08:30.852Z INFO - Status: Image is up to date for 10.1.0.4:13209/appsvc/node:18-lts_20220228.1.tuxprod
2024-08-12T17:08:30.864Z INFO - Pull Image successful, Time taken: 0 Seconds
2024-08-12T17:08:30.904Z INFO - Starting container for site
2024-08-12T17:08:30.905Z INFO - docker run -d --expose=8080 --name ......

And yet(!), the version being used to deploy the app is v16 which of course causes the deployment to fail.
2024-08-12T16:18:09.714643966Z   _____                               
2024-08-12T16:18:09.714690368Z   /  _  \ __________ _________   ____  
2024-08-12T16:18:09.714696968Z  /  /_\  \___   /  |  \_  __ \_/ __ \ 
2024-08-12T16:18:09.714701869Z /    |    \/    /|  |  /|  | \/\  ___/ 
2024-08-12T16:18:09.714706569Z \____|__  /_____ \____/ |__|    \___  >
2024-08-12T16:18:09.714711469Z         \/      \/                  \/ 
2024-08-12T16:18:09.714716169Z A P P   S E R V I C E   O N   L I N U X
2024-08-12T16:18:09.714720869Z 
2024-08-12T16:18:09.714725270Z Documentation: http://aka.ms/webapp-linux
2024-08-12T16:18:09.714729770Z NodeJS quickstart: https://aka.ms/node-qs
2024-08-12T16:18:09.714734270Z NodeJS Version : v16.13.1 <--------
2024-08-12T16:18:09.714738770Z Note: Any data outside '/home' is not persisted
2024-08-12T16:18:09.714743271Z 
2024-08-12T16:18:09.965438943Z Starting periodic command scheduler: cron.
2024-08-12T16:18:10.058709071Z Cound not find build manifest file at '/home/site/wwwroot/oryx-manifest.toml'
2024-08-12T16:18:10.058795475Z Could not find operation ID in manifest. Generating an operation id...
2024-08-12T16:18:10.058804876Z Build Operation ID: fa38d167-796d-4f30-af51-d11537e25846
2024-08-12T16:18:10.281955010Z Environment Variables for Application Insight's IPA Codeless Configuration exists..
2024-08-12T16:18:10.289068956Z Writing output script to '/opt/startup/startup.sh'
2024-08-12T16:18:10.310169580Z Running #!/bin/sh
2024-08-12T16:18:10.310198181Z 
2024-08-12T16:18:10.310205082Z # Enter the source directory to make sure the script runs where the user expects
2024-08-12T16:18:10.310211182Z cd "/home/site/wwwroot"
2024-08-12T16:18:10.310216482Z 
2024-08-12T16:18:10.310222183Z export NODE_PATH=/usr/local/lib/node_modules:$NODE_PATH
2024-08-12T16:18:10.310227883Z if [ -z "$PORT" ]; then
2024-08-12T16:18:10.310233183Z      export PORT=8080
2024-08-12T16:18:10.310238583Z fi
2024-08-12T16:18:10.310243784Z 
2024-08-12T16:18:10.310248984Z PATH="$PATH:/home/site/wwwroot" bash /home/site/wwwroot/start-dev.sh
2024-08-12T16:18:10.326757685Z Starting custom deployment script...
2024-08-12T16:18:10.354607138Z Expected: v18.20.1
2024-08-12T16:18:10.366245803Z Actual: v16.13.1

What am I missing?
Thank you!

please share your dockerfile.

I'm not using a dockerfile. The dockerfile is Azure's. It is created automatically based on the configurations for the runtime (or so they claim!)

Please provide your package.json file or if possible share your github repo

How are you deploying your app to Azure App Service via GitHub or the VS Code extension?

I'm deploying via GH. I unfortunately cannot share either the repo or the package.json. But I could potentially answer questions if you have any?

I created a sample Nodejs application and have successfully deployed it to Azure App Service via GitHub actions.
To avoid the error, you're encountering

Add the engines field to package.json file, this field tells which version of Node.js your project needs to work.

My package.json file:
{
  "name": "errortest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.19.2"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=18.0.0"
  }
}


Thanks to @Richard Huf for the clear steps, I referred to this  doc  and added the  .nvmrc  file to the root diectory of the project.

Add the node.js version you are using in this file:
v18.20.1

in .yml file I've added


name: Get Node.js version from .nvmrc
id: nvmrc
run: echo "NODE_VERSION=$(cat .nvmrc)" >> $GITHUB_ENV

This command reads the Node.js version from .nvmrc file.
Complete workflow file:
name: Build and deploy Node.js app to Azure Web App - nodetest18
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Get Node.js version from .nvmrc
        id: nvmrc
        run: echo "NODE_VERSION=$(cat .nvmrc)" >> $GITHUB_ENV
      - name: Set up Node.js version
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: ${{ env.NODE_VERSION }}
      - name: npm install, build
        run: |
          npm install
          npm run build --if-present
      - name: Zip artifact for deployment
        run: zip release.zip ./* -r
      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: node-app
          path: release.zip
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}
    permissions:
      id-token: write #This is required for requesting the JWT
    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: node-app
      - name: Unzip artifact for deployment
        run: unzip release.zip    
      - name: Login to Azure
        uses: azure/login@v2
        with:
          client-id: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_CLIENTID_<client-id> }}
          tenant-id: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_TENANTID_<tenant-id> }}
          subscription-id: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_SUBSCRIPTIONID_<subscription-id> }}
      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v3
        with:
          app-name: 'nodetest18'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          package: .

Successfully deployed the app to Azure App Service via GitHub actions without any issues.


